# Parsing CSV file where encapsulator in content ain't escaped properly

Tags: java, excel, apache, csv, apache-commons

Hi I have a CSV File where the encapsulator character is not escaped properly.

Example

```
uerf@einf.erf,"uhrege gerjhhg er<span style="background-color: rgb(0,153,0);">eriueiru kernger</span><font color="#009900"><span style="background-color: rgb(255,255,255);"> weiufhuweifbw fhew fibwefbw</span></font><div><font color="#009900"><span style="background-color: rgb(255,255,255);">wekifbwe fewf</span></font></div><div><font color="#009900"><span style="background-color: rgb(255,255,255);">weiuifgewbfjew f</span></font></div>",18-Oct-2016,
```

Delimiter -> ,

Encapsulator -> "

It breaks when I try to read using commons-csv reader ,
throws a ' `invalid char between encapsulated token and delimiter`' Exception .

However Microsoft excel seems to open the file perfectly.
Any ideas on how to procced ? .

How does one parse CSV files where the encapsulator is not escaped properly ?.Excel seems to open such files fine.

Comment: I found this useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210568/java-csv-parser-with-unescaped-quotes              Libre office and excel seem to be taking an educated guess . How do I make the same?

Answer (score 1):

If you can't fix this at the source (i.e. generate a well-formed csv), and you want to parse this yourself, you could go the easy way:

Scan field1 up to `,"` - field2 up to `",` - rest is field3 (trailing comma?).

Of course if a `",` occurs in the html field, there's a problem. You could solve that by first scanning up to `,"`, and then backwards (starting at the end of the line) to `",`.

If there are more fields than you show here, you could look for a `,` combined with a `"` (both combinations, could also be `","`) and hope those do not appear in the field data.

Answer (score 0):

[univocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) has a CSV parser that can handle this sort of input properly.

```
    //first configure the parser
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.setUnescapedQuoteHandling(UnescapedQuoteHandling.STOP_AT_CLOSING_QUOTE);

    //then create a parser and parse your input line:
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
    String[] result = parser.parseLine("" +
            "uerf@einf.erf,\"uhrege gerjhhg er<span style=\"background-color: rgb(0,153,0);\">eriueiru kernger</span><font color=\"#009900\"><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255,255,255);\"> weiufhuweifbw fhew fibwefbw</span></font><div><font color=\"#009900\"><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255,255,255);\">wekifbwe fewf</span></font></div><div><font color=\"#009900\"><span style=\"background-color: rgb(255,255,255);\">weiuifgewbfjew f</span></font></div>\",18-Oct-2016,");

    //here's the result (one value per line)
    for (String v : result) {
        System.out.println(v);
    }
```

This prints:

```
uerf@einf.erf
uhrege gerjhhg er<span style="background-color: rgb(0,153,0);">eriueiru kernger</span><font color="#009900"><span style="background-color: rgb(255,255,255);"> weiufhuweifbw fhew fibwefbw</span></font><div><font color="#009900"><span style="background-color: rgb(255,255,255);">wekifbwe fewf</span></font></div><div><font color="#009900"><span style="background-color: rgb(255,255,255);">weiuifgewbfjew f</span></font></div>
18-Oct-2016
null
```

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache v2.0 license)